# How to make React params 1 item

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I make these three params 1 item for example **let {productCode, value, vender} = item**.

I have already declared them. But I would like to send them to my cart as props.

```
import React from "react";
import "bootstrap";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function ItemDetail(props) {
  const params = useParams();
  let productCode = params.productCode; // <-- access `productCode` param
  let vendor = params.vendor; // <-- access `vendor` param
  let value = params.value; // <-- access `value` param

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <p>product id: {productCode}</p>
        <p>price: {value}</p>
        <p>vendor: {vendor}</p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default ItemDetail;
```

Comment: Do you mean `const item = { productCode, value, vender };`? What cart are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  const params = useParams();
  let { productCode, vendor, value}  = params;
  let combined = {productCode, vendor, value};
```

Destructure and assign the required values to variables. Then combine them to a single object.

Comment: Thank you. This worked and was so helpuful